# Pdo Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in php

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, warnings

I am trying to make a sql query using PDO in PHP and something is going wrong which i can not figure out.

Here is my code:

```
    *//Connection file*

    < ? php

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oopdo';

    $db = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');

    ?>

    *//Index file*

    < ? php

    try{
        require_once 'pdo_connection.php';

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM names'.
                'ORDER BY name';
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $error = $ex->getMessage();

    }


    ?>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Looping direct over SELECT query</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Meaning</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>


            foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){ (line 35)


            <tr>
                <td> echo $row['name']; </td>
                <td> echo $row['meaning']; </td>
                <td> echo $row['gender']; </td>
            </tr>

             }
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 35

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: `PDO::query` may return `FALSE`.

Comment: try your query in phpmyadmin to see if works as expected

Comment: What view/templating model are you using? You might need to put values into a `$data[]`array before passing into the templating engine.

Answer (score 3):

**What you've really done wrong:**

You haven't checked the return status of your query, which has failed with a syntax error. You should use code something like this:

```
$result = $db->query($sql);
if ($result !== false) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
       // do stuff
    }
} else {
    echo 'The SQL query failed with error '.$db->errorCode;
}
```

**What you've actually done wrong:**

Where you've split your query over two lines you've contrived to omit
some whitespace. Your query is submitted as

```
SELECT * FROM namesORDER BY name
```

Add an extra space in your string immediately after `names`

Comment: You are totally right! Thank you very much!